# Filtering data by datetime variable R

Tags: r, datetime, filter, time

Let's say I have the following dataframe on which I create a DateTime column:

```
df <- read.table(text="
Date         Time   pH
1976-01-26   0:00   4.00
1976-01-26   0:15   4.05
1976-01-26   1:00   4.50
1976-01-26   1:15   4.50
1976-01-27   0:00   4.00
1976-01-27   0:15   4.50
1076-01-27   2:00   4.00", header=T)

df$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$Date, df$Time))
```

Hence, my data is the following:

```
        Date Time   pH            DateTime
1 1976-01-26 0:00 4.00 1976-01-26 00:00:00
2 1976-01-26 0:15 4.05 1976-01-26 00:15:00
3 1976-01-26 1:00 4.50 1976-01-26 01:00:00
4 1976-01-26 1:15 4.50 1976-01-26 01:15:00
5 1976-01-27 0:00 4.00 1976-01-27 00:00:00
6 1976-01-27 0:15 4.20 1976-01-27 00:15:00
7 1076-01-27 2:00 3.80 1076-01-27 02:00:00
```

How do I filter according to the `DateTime` column only the rows for which the minutes are `00:00`?
For example `00:00:00, 01:00:00, 02:00:00` have to be in the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `filter` where the time is '00:00:00' you could use `as_hms` to consider just time of day for filtering:

```
library(dplyr)
library(hms)

filter(df, as_hms(DateTime) == as_hms('00:00:00'))
```

To `filter` even hours (where number of minutes is zero), you can use `minute` from `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)

filter(df, minute(DateTime) == 0)
```

Likewise, if you want to `filter` on both zero minutes and seconds, you could do:

```
filter(df, minute(DateTime) == 0 & second(DateTime) == 0)
```

Comment: sorry my question was wrong, I edited it in order for it to be exactly what I need to obtain

Comment: @AntonioMastroianni See edited answer. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Is it possible that the hms package used alongside readr package slows down reading of data?

Comment: @AntonioMastroianni Not sure I follow - `readr` package uses `hms` already. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/index.html

Comment: oh ok, then I think I have uninstalled and reinstalled hms. But anyways, after this operations the data I was using started taking a lot more time to be read by the ```read_csv()``` function

Comment: Can you try using `fread` from `data.table`? How big is the data file?

Comment: It is almost 3GB

Comment: Make sure you have enough RAM free. Consider use `fread` as mentioned. Consider reading in by chunks. Also, there are other SO answers about reading in large csv files. Or feel free to post another question on this. I hope this might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are handling date, I believe Ben's solution is more suitable for you. My approach is for general string matching.

Here we use `grepl()` to find pattern and return a logical value for `filter()`.

**UPDATED: Since you have updated your question, I have also updated my code.**

```
df %>% as_tibble() %>% filter(grepl("0.:00:00", DateTime))
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Date       Time     pH DateTime           
  <chr>      <chr> <dbl> <dttm>             
1 1976-01-26 0:00    4   1976-01-26 00:00:00
2 1976-01-26 1:00    4.5 1976-01-26 01:00:00
3 1976-01-27 0:00    4   1976-01-27 00:00:00
4 1076-01-27 2:00    4   1076-01-27 02:00:00
```

Comment: sorry my question was wrong, I edited it in order for it to be exactly what I need to obtain

Comment: Updated accordingly.